# RDS Proxy DatabaseConnectionRequests

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I am having a higher number of DatabaseConnectionRequests on the RDS proxy. I am not sure how should I interpret it? I tried the AWS documentation but it did not help:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.monitoring.html

1. What is DatabaseConnectionRequests matric, what does it represent?
2. Does it represent connection Requests between proxy and database or between application and proxy?
3. What will be the impact on the RDS database instance if this metric will keep on getting higher and higher?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.